# The LINQ expression node type 'Invoke' is not supported in LINQ to Entities in entity framework

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, expression, predicate

can anyone help me out in solving my issue. I am using the code given below:

```
public IEnumerable<InvoiceHeader> Getdata(Expression<Func<InvoiceHeader, bool>> predicate)
{
    return AccountsContext.InvoiceHeaders.Include("Company").Include("Currency")
        .Include("BusinessPartnerRoleList").Include("DocumentType")
        .Where(predicate);
}
```

.....

In my code I am using as below

```
Expression<Func<InvoiceHeader, bool>> predicate = PredicateBuilder.True<InvoiceHeader>();
predicate = predicate.And(o => o.CompanyId == oInvoiceHeader.CompanyId);
List<InvoiceHeader> lstInvheader=Getdata(predicate).ToList();
```

By doing this I am getting the exception . [System.NotSupportedException] ---
{"The LINQ expression node type 'Invoke' is not supported in LINQ to Entities."}

Comment: You mention an exception. I think you forgot to add it.

Comment: If I remember correctly, this is due to how the PredicateBuilder you probably took from internet works. Try with this version: https://github.com/jbevain/mono.linq.expressions/blob/master/Mono.Linq.Expressions/PredicateBuilder.cs

Answer (score 49):

This problem can be solved using the AsExpandable() method present in LINQKIT by Joe Albahari. He's the same creator of `PredicateBuilder` that I see you're using.

> If querying with Entity Framework, change the last line to this:
>
> `return objectContext.Products.AsExpandable().Where(predicate);`

You can grab LINQKIT DLL [here](http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/linqkit.aspx) or install it through a NuGet package [here](http://nuget.org/packages/LinqKit).

It'll certainly solve your problem because it has solved mine.

Answer (score 1):

Linq to EF queries are translated into SQL. that exception means that the runtime can't translate your code into SQL query because it's something not supported in SQL.

you can either change your code to omit the parts that SQL doesn't support, or you can pull datas from the Database first by calling .AsEnumerable() like below, then you can do everything since it's Linq-to-Objects

```
public IEnumerable<InvoiceHeader> Getdata(Expression<Func<InvoiceHeader, bool>> predicate)
{
    return AccountsContext.InvoiceHeaders.Include("Company").Include("Currency")
        .Include("BusinessPartnerRoleList").Include("DocumentType")
        .AsEnumerable()
        .Where(predicate);
}
```

Comment: But by doing this i am getting the following error message 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<ShipNet.Accounting.Entities.InvoiceHeader>' does not contain a definition for 'Where' and the best extension method overload 'System.Linq.Enumerable.Where<TSource>(System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<TSource>, System.Func<TSource,int,bool>)' has some invalid arguments

Comment: Doing a where after .AsEnumerable() means that ALL records will be sucked in. Use this advice with EXTREME CAUTION.

Answer (score -2):

I had a case where "InvoiceHeaders" from your case was IEnumerable. Adding .AsQueryable() solved the issue.
Reference: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/meek/archive/2008/05/02/linq-to-entities-combining-predicates.aspx

So, the code in the end looked like

```
return AccountsContext.InvoiceHeaders // omitted includes
    .AsQueryable()
    .Where(predicate);
```