# LINQ to Entities Does not Support Invoke

Tags: c#, linq-to-entities

I have the following query in LINQ to Entities:

```
var query = from p in db.Products
            where p.Price > 10M
            select p;
```

At this point the query has not executed, and I want to write a query that will return true/false based on some conditions:

```
return query.Any(p => p.IsInStock &&
               (p.Category == "Beverage" ||
               p.Category == "Other"));
```

This works fine; however, I would like to get some reuse out of my code. I have many methods that need to filter based on if the category is a Beverage or Other, so I tried creating a delegate:

```
Func<Product, bool> eligibleForDiscount = (product) => product.Category == "Beverage" || product.Category == "Other";
```

I wanted to substitute the inline check with the delegate:

```
return query.Any(p => p.IsInStock && eligibleForDiscount(p));
```

This gives me an error saying that LINQ to Entities doesn't support Invoke. Why can't I substitute the inline code for a delegate like this, and is there any way I can accomplish my reuse some other way?

Comment: possible duplicate of [The LINQ expression node type 'Invoke' is not supported in LINQ to Entities in entity framework](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8741667/the-linq-expression-node-type-invoke-is-not-supported-in-linq-to-entities-in-e)

Comment: Considering that question does not have an accepted answer and I have no idea what this PredicateBuilder is, I don't consider this question a duplicate.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Recall that under the hood `Linq-to-{DATABASE}` is just transforming the `IQueryable` you've produced into Sql.

You can't inline code like that because an `Invoke` (the method you're actually calling when you call a `Func` or `Action`) has no consistent way to transform it into a sql statement (you could be doing *anything* in there).

That said you can reuse parts by splitting it up:

```
var query = from p in db.Products
            where p.Price > 10M
            select p;

query = query.Where(p => p.IsInStock);
query = query.Where(p => p.Category == "Beverage" || p.Category == "Other");
return query.Any();
```

Both those can be put into methods that take an `IQueryable<Product>` and return the same (but filtered). Then you can reuse to your heart's content!

Comment: So your suggestion would be to have a method that takes IQueryable<Product> and return IQueryable<Product> instead of a delegate. I guess they both do the same thing :)

Comment: They do exactly the same thing, and it's much more reusable...Methods and functions that Take IQueryable and return IQueryable are really powerful that way.

Comment: As an added bonus, this can also be made into an extension method too which provides for custom slick looking query.WhereIsInAnyCategory("Beverage", "Other") (or query.WhereBeverageOrOther() ) type syntax on an IQueryable<Product> interface.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that `IQueryable` needs to generate a SQL expression to pass to RDBMS, and it cannot do it when all it has is an opaque predicate.

The obvious but inefficient way is to rewrite your query as follows:

```
return query.Where(p => p.IsInStock).AsEnumerable().Any(eligibleForDiscount);
```

A less trivial way would be as follows:

```
bool GotEligible(Expression<Func<Product,bool>> pred) {
    return query.Where(p => p.IsInStock).Any(pred);
}
```

Note how instead of a predicate this method takes a *predicate expression*. Now it is transparent to the EF, and can be converted to a SQL query without a problem.

Comment: btw, you want to get rid of the `(p)` in the `Any` clause

Comment: And *probably* you meant `GotEligible` ;)

Answer (score 0):

As long as you stick with IQueryable, you can keep reusable querys in functions.

```
  public IQueryable<Product> EligibleForDiscount(IQueryable<Product> products)
  {
       return products.Where(p => product.Category == "Beverage" || 
                                  product.Category == "Other");
  }
```

Now call it like any other function:

```
  IQueryable<Product> query = (from p in db.Products
                               where p.Price > 10M
                               select p);

  query = EligibleForDiscount(query);
```