# Howto use predicates in LINQ to Entities for Entity Framework objects

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq-to-entities, predicate, linqkit

I'm using LINQ to Entities for Entity Framework objects in my Data Access Layer.

My goal is to filter as much as I can from the database, without applying filtering logic to  in-memory results.

For that purpose Business Logic Layer passes a predicate to Data Access Layer.

I mean

```
Func<MyEntity, bool>
```

So, if I use this predicate directly, like

```
public IQueryable<MyEntity> GetAllMatchedEntities(Func<MyEntity, Boolean> isMatched)
{
    return qry = _Context.MyEntities.Where(x => isMatched(x));
}
```

I'm getting the exception

> [System.NotSupportedException] --- {"The LINQ expression node type
>   'Invoke' is not supported in LINQ to Entities."}

Solution in [**that question**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8741667/the-linq-expression-node-type-invoke-is-not-supported-in-linq-to-entities-in-e) suggests to use AsExpandable() method from [**LINQKit**](http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/linqkit.aspx) library.

But again, using

```
public IQueryable<MyEntity> GetAllMatchedEntities(Func<MyEntity, Boolean> isMatched)
{
    return qry = _Context.MyEntities.AsExpandable().Where(x => isMatched(x));
}
```

I'm getting the exception

> Unable to cast object of type
>   'System.Linq.Expressions.FieldExpression' to type
>   'System.Linq.Expressions.LambdaExpression'

Is there way to use predicate in LINQ to Entities query for Entity Framework objects, so that it is correctly transformed it into a SQL statement.

Thank you.

Comment: I don't want to interfere, but exposing `IQueryable` and expression parameters is generally considered to be a bad idea. It's better to add specification parameters to `GetAllMatchedEntities` (like `int minimumAge`) and build the query inside the method.

Comment: @GertArnold not everyone agrees re `IQueryable' https://medium.com/@hoagsie/youre-all-doing-entity-framework-wrong-ea0c40e20502

Answer (score 62, accepted):

You don't need LinqKit to do this. Just remember to use

```
Expression<Func<MyEntity, bool>>
```

instead of

```
Func<MyEntity, bool>
```

Something like this:

```
public IQueryable<MyEntity> GetAllMatchedEntities(Expression<Func<MyEntity, Boolean>> predicate)
{
    return _Context.MyEntities.Where(predicate);
}
```

You have to use Expression because Linq to Entities needs to translate your lambda to SQL.

When you use Func your lambda is compiled to IL but when using Expression it is an expression tree that Linq to Entities can transverse and convert.

This works with expressions that Linq to Entities understands.

If it keeps failing then your expression does something that Linq to Entities can not translate to SQL. In that case I don't think LinqKit will help.

### Edit:

There is no conversion needed. Just define the method GetAllMatchedEntities with an Expression parameter and use it in the same way you would with a Func parameter. The compiler does the rest.

There are three ways you can use GetAllMatchedEntities.

1) With an inline lambda expression:

```
this.GetAllMatchedEntities(x => x.Age > 18)
```

2) Define your Expression as a field (can be a variable also)

```
private readonly Expression<Func<MyEntity, bool>> IsMatch = x => x.Age > 18;
...then use it
this.GetAllMatchedEntities(IsMatch)
```

3) You can create your expression manually. The downsize is more code and you miss the compile-time checks.

```
public Expression<Func<MyEntity, bool>>  IsMatchedExpression()
{
    var parameterExpression = Expression.Parameter(typeof (MyEntity));
    var propertyOrField = Expression.PropertyOrField(parameterExpression, "Age");
    var binaryExpression = Expression.GreaterThan(propertyOrField, Expression.Constant(18));
    return Expression.Lambda<Func<MyEntity, bool>>(binaryExpression, parameterExpression);
}
```

Comment: To my shame I know almost nothing about Expression. If I for example  have `public Boolean IsMatched(MyEntity entity)
{
    return entity.Age > 18;
}` for my predicate - how can it be converted to `Expression<Func<MyEntity, bool>>` ?

Comment: @user274947 I have edited my answer with the example you gave.

Comment: I've tried your code, but I receive compile error `Argument 1:cannot convert from 'method group' to 'System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<System.Func<TEntity, bool>>'`. Looks like compiler waits for `this.GetAllMatchedEntities(this.IsMatched(SOMETHING))` instead of `this.GetAllMatchedEntities(this.IsMatched)`..

Comment: @user274947 You are right, you can almost use it the same way. I've added some examples of how you can use GetAllMatchedEntities.

Comment: How would you join multiple tables with this approach ?

Answer (score 4):

Methods used in Linq to Entities must be canonically mapped by the Linq provider in order to work.  Since the Linq provider, EF in your case, was unable to map your predicate to an internal method, it threw an error.

> For LINQ scenarios, queries against the Entity Framework involve
>   mapping certain CLR methods to methods on the underlying data source
>   through canonical functions. Any method calls in a LINQ to Entities
>   query that are not explicitly mapped to a canonical function will
>   result in a runtime NotSupportedException exception being thrown

Source:  CLR Method to Canonical Function Mapping  (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738681.aspx)

You can try to take those methods that **ARE** mapped and chain them into your Linq expression, or use a stored procedure.  But until EF supports all of the CLR, you will be left with having to find a work-around.

On the plus side, each release seems to add a bit more to the canonical list.

Worth reading as a possible work-around:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd456857.aspx

Comment: Thanks. It was very clarifying.